# Mounting CVFS as a specific user

Tags: linux, permissions, mount

I'm mounting a StorNext mount point on a new stack, and the user that is accessing the files on the StorNext/CVFS mount point is different from the old stack (ie the old Stack uses UID of 500, and the new stack uses a UID of 1000, despite the usernames actually being the same).

One easy way around this if the mount point is an NFS share, is to specify "uid=500,gid=500" in the mount options, and apply them to the /etc/fstab, but this is clearly not an NFS mount point. I've tried this method on the CVFS point, and it did not seem to take.

Any other solution?
my other two solutions are to:

1) change the permissions on all the files on the mount point to 500 where it is set to 1000 (using a find command piped into a chown command).

2) change the UID to 500 on the system, reinstall all of the software, and see if that works

Both of these solutions will take WAY more time than something as easy as specifying the UID on the mount point, like an NFS share.

Thank you for you aids!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a workaround for this.

I ended up basically following this post to change the UID and GID, and that seemed to do the trick.

https://muffinresearch.co.uk/linux-changing-uids-and-gids-for-user/

Caveats include

- having root access
- a second user or ssh directly as root 
  (it becomes difficult to change some things for a currently logged in user)
- I didn't use a blanket update on "/" because I had not NOT touch networked drives / mount points. So I setup a list of find commands to do this for me, explicitly naming parent directories.

Summary of that blog post, thanks Stuart! :

```
usermod -u <NEWUID> <LOGIN>
groupmod -g <NEWGID> <GROUP>
find / -user <OLDUID> -exec chown -h <NEWUID> {} \;
find / -group <OLDGID> -exec chgrp -h <NEWGID> {} \;
usermod -g <NEWGID> <LOGIN>
```

use chown -c to see all the files you're changing!